# Is .ogg for Audio or for Video format?

Tags: file-type

What is the `.ogg` format? Is that used for audio files or used for video files?
I found two examples in `/usr/share/example-content/Ubuntu_Free_Culture_Showcase`

[image]

Comment: http://www.vorbis.com/faq/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ogg is technically a container format. It can include audio, video, and even text. Typically, it uses Vorbis audio and Theora video.

The current recommendation from the developer is to use the .ogv for video and .ogg for audio, but previously recommended .ogg for everything.

More at [Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogg).

`sox` or `ffmpeg` can help you determine what the container contains.

Answer (score 0):

Both. OGG files can be either Video or Audio, you just need to play it to see. As for the files you are asking about, those are just default files that come with Ubuntu.